# Do all the daemons indicated by configFiles/scripts/links in /etc/{init,init.d} start at the boot?

Tags: boot, filesystem, performance, services, init

1. Are all the daemons (services) indicated by configuration-files/scripts/links in `/etc/init/`, `/etc/init.d/` meant to start at the boot; so can I assume those directories being like start-up directory for the processes during the boot-up?
2. Keeping in mind multiprocessing, will stopping some or more of those from getting to start at boot actually speed-up the system boot time?
3. Are the processes just triggered to start or is there some return code checking going on too?

Answer (score 2):

1. No, `/etc/init.d/` and `/etc/init` are used to store the startup scripts of various processes used on your system. Having a script in these directory doesn't mean that they are going to start.
   For the script in `/etc/init.d`, there should be a link in one of the `/etc/rc*.d` directories to start or stop them (symbolic link) managed by the **update-rc.d** tool.
   Services in these directories are usually started / stopped / restarted by the `sudo service <service name> <action>` command.
   For the scripts in `/etc/init`, these are part of the new boot mechanism offered by **upstart**. The file in the `/etc/init` directory contains information about when and how to start and stop the service they offer.
   Services in this directory are usually started / stopped / restarted by `sudo <action> <service name>`.
2. Of course, less services to start means less time to wait during boot. But take care of not disabling services needed by your system to function properly (like **udev**, **dbus**, ...)
3. For services started from `/etc/init.d`, the startup script should implement in it various check to report that the service is well started or not. Usually this translate by a line saying " started" or " not started" or some other error message. This appears at the console and should also be logged into `/var/log/boot.log`.
   For services started by **upstart** (using `/etc/init` directory), the **upstart** process itself provides a way to automatically restart services that may fail, manage the dependencies between them (start *service1* prior to *service2* if *service2* needs *service1* to start / function).

Comment: do you imply a sequential start of the services?

Comment: @rusty: for the services managed by **upstart** I don't know if they can be started in parallel or not. For the services started using the old way (`/etc/init.d` and the `/etc/rc*.d` directories), scripts are started one after the other using the order defined by the name of the symbolic link in `/etc/rc*.d`. The name is of the form SxxNAME or KxxNAME -> S to start, K to kill and xx is a number to order the sequential start of the services (lower number are started first).

Comment: I'm still confused about which among or all of the processes `/etc/rc?.d/*` has more effect on the boot-up time.. Is it just those in `/etc/rcS.d/` which seems the first ones to start? I read a little about the run levels and that got me to assume that those in `rc0.d, rc6.d` should not affect the boot nor should those with run levels 1 to 5, but again I can also see some S* scripts in run-level 0 and 6! What am I not getting here?

Comment: By default, an Ubuntu system boot into runlevel 2, so the one in `/etc/rc2.d` will be run. Runlevel 0 is the shutdown, runlevel 6 is the reboot. S is the single-user mode (or recovery mode). Which process has more effect the boot-up time is process dependent ! You have to review all of them one by one to see which one is taken a lot of time to be started. There is no magic in there, just try and error.

Comment: actually I've read 1 is the single user mode and S is the first one to start and takes care of the rest.. also some S* scripts in runlevels 0 and 6 confuses me! ..so I assume even there's some priority for the `rc?.d/` directories in Debian perhaps, first S and then the other (default 2)?!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

Bum is a boot up manager,it allows u to detect and manipulate the daemons and processes which start at boot up.